# Android update fragment from an AsyncTask from another class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an object which has a method which executes `AsyncTask`s and stores the results in the object's instance variables. There is a `fragment` that shows the results. It is all good as long as the `fragment` is shown after the `AsyncTask` has finished. **BUT the `fragment` may be shown before the `AsyncTask` is finished and by that time the results are still `null`.**

**How can I tell the `fragment` to wait and update the view when the `AsyncTask` is finished?**

I am trying to do something like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(...){
  myFragment.updateView(); //custom method to update the view of that specific fragment
}
```

The app exits without anything being shown in logCat.
Please tell me to clarify the question if there is anything unclear.

Comment: so can you debug after your asyntask method run , it returns correnct or is is already empty?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar can you clarify your question? My `AsyncTask` runs really well. Just that I have no idea how do I tell the fragment to update from the object's `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I mean did you check your objects are realy populated correctly after your asyntask method run?

Comment: Your fragment shouldn't wait for anything since it updates itself by invoke of `updateView` method. First time it appear, just check if its data source object(s) is(are) null and show a kind of "Loading..." message instead of data...

Comment: @Salauyou what I mean by wait is not really pausing anything. The fragment has a `ProgressBar` to tell user it is loading. I need to know how can I invoke the `updateView()` method in the fragment from an Object's `AsyncTask`

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar the objects should be all right.

Comment: @CarsonIp you already do it in `onPostExecute`, don't you?

Comment: @CarsonIp now I understand: your app fails when you add this code in it... So you should try to invoke `updateView()` in ways other than from `onPostExecute()` to look whether everything is correct with this method.

Comment: @Salauyou I think there are some problems with the reference. I do something like `Fragment fragment = new MyCustomFragment(); myObject.fragmentInstance = fragment; ...(then some fragment transaction things)` In `onPostExecute`, I am invoking the `myObject.fragmentInstance.updateView()`

Comment: on your view have list and you dont see the updated news?

Comment: @CarsonIp references look absolutely clear and correct

Comment: @Salauyou Oops, I am referencing the wrong fragment and caused some casting problems. The fragment that has the `updateView()` method is a nested fragment `MyCustomMemberFragment` under the fragment that I am creating, i.e. `MyCustomFragment`. Complex problem.

Comment: @CarsonIp so did you succeeded?

Comment: @Salauyou storing the fragment in this way is causing problem when the fragment does not exist / is not active. How to solve?